# Need Help Creating Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

I currently have a large ecommerce store with over 4000+ URLs. We are in the process of finishing up the development on the brand new, re-platformed version of the website, and unfortunately that has led to a change in the URL format for all of our products.

I am not very familiar with the syntax to use to create the RewriteRule to handle the scenario below. If you can help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

**Scenerio:**

Original URL: http://www.example.com/p-22-some-product-seo-name.aspx

This URL needs to be converted to...

New URL: http://www.example.com/some-product-seo-name

Notice, that the first part of the original URL the (`p-xx-`) needs to be removed. Where `xx` is the product id that was used in the old URL. That ID is not always 2 digits and can be 1-8 digits in length depending on the product.

Also, the `.aspx` needs to be removed from the end of the url, leaving just the hyphenated SEO name.

I have tried the following (and many variations of it) but to no avail!

```
RewriteRule ^p-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.aspx$ /$2 [R=301, NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should be changed to the following:

```
^p-([\d]{1,8})-([\w-]+)\.aspx$
```

Where the first capture allows for between one and eight digits, and the second capture allows for alpha-numeric characters, underscores, and hyphens.

Comment: thanks for the answer, when I plugin your suggestion with the rest of the statement, I still get a 500 error. The final statement I used is: 

`RewriteRule ^p-([\d]{1,2})-([\w-]+)\.aspx$ /$2 [R=301, NC]`

Sorry if I am missing something obvious. I am a Windows guy by trade so working with Apache and ModRewrite is not my best skill set.

NOTE: I changed the 8 to a 2 just for testing a specific scenario but I also got the 500 error when using that as well.

Comment: I was actually able to figure out the 500 error thanks to your original answer. It turns out the last part of the rule was formatted incorrectly. I changed the rule to the following and it works like a charm. 

    `RewriteRule ^p-([\d]{1,8})-([\w-]+)\.aspx$ /$2 [L,R=301,NC]`

Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: Ah, yes - my answer only changed your expression, and did not make provision for the `L` flag. Glad it's working now.